# Get Ember-Data REST response value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember: 1.0.0-rc.6

Ember-Data: e999edb (2013-07-06 06:03:59 -0700)

I make a REST call (POST) to login a user.
Server response is ok.
I need the ID from the server, but i only got the ID with "setTimeout".

I think this is not the right way.

What is my mistake?

Within Controller i call:

```
var login = App.Login.createRecord(this.getProperties("email", "password"));

login.on("didCreate", function(record) {
  console.log(record.get("id"));     // ID is null
  console.log(record.get("email"));
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(login.get("id"));     // ID is available
  console.log(login.get("email"));
}, 500);

DS.defaultStore.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right -- there's a bug in ember-data where the `materializeData` event, which basically sets the id and unwraps the server response doesn't happen until AFTER the `didCreate` callback. So what's happening is that in your `login.on("didCreate" ....)` callback, the record still hasn't materialized yet.

This seems to still be an issue -- see this thread for more information: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/405#issuecomment-17107045

**Workaround**

Your work around is fine, but an easier (cleaner?) one is to wrap your callback actions in a `Ember.run.next`:

```
login.on("didCreate", function(record) {
  Ember.run.next(function() {
    console.log(record.get("id"));     // ID should be set
    console.log(record.get("email"));
  }
});
```

This way, at least you don't need to deal with the timeout.

I believe this works by delaying the actions until the next run loop, and by then the materialization should have already happened. [More on the Ember run loop](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/)

Source: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/405#issuecomment-18726035

Comment: Thank you! In my case i can use now an observer for the id.
    idObserver: function() {
      /* ... */
    }.observes("id")

Comment: is this solution working , i have tried more than couple of time . This is not working , and record is materialized to get id from it , still id returns null