# Ember - Record ID not returned (null) after successful insertion to the backend

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
.
.
.

var project = this.store.createRecord('project', {
                name: projectName,
            });

            project.save();
            alert(project.get('id') + project.get('name'));
.
.
.
```

This adds the record successfully to the db and the front end is automatically refreshed to reflect these changes. When the alert is executed however, only the name is printed.

For the ID i get null.

Basically I need to get the id value returned from the server after the record has been successfully isnerted. I checked the returned JSON:

```
{"project":{"id":6,"name":"dfgdgf", "created_at":"2014-01-02T08:37:57.491Z","updated_at":"2014-01-02T08:37:57.491Z"}}
```

so the id field is contained in the json response. Could the problem occur because the server also returns two fields (created_at and updated_at) which are not found in the ember model??

Thank you so much!

EDIT:

I included `created_at` and `updated_at` in my model in ember and am still getting null when I try to call `project.get('id');`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: the data from the server are returned asynchronously, so you actually need to use a callback function and call alert, or use the returned data in that function.

Comment: @melc, could you point me to a link that would give me some guidance?

Comment: sure, possible solutions can be found in these threads, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574133/is-handling-custom-server-side-errors-in-ember-data-when-saving-model-possible  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790671/get-ember-data-rest-response-value

Comment: melc, you can post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks! Did not know that it is a known bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data from the server are returned asynchronously, so to is required to use a callback function and call alert, or use the returned data in that function.

Possible solutions can be found in the following threads,

[is handling custom server side errors in ember-data when saving model possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574133/is-handling-custom-server-side-errors-in-ember-data-when-saving-model-possible)

[Get Ember-Data REST response value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790671/get-ember-data-rest-response-value)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it. Why do you think it is so difficult to implement the save() function in ember such that it works syncrhonously?

Comment: @Dragan actually this is how ajax requests work, calls to a server with asynchronous responses. This means that callback functions are required in all cases to handle the responses. In ember-data this behaviour is accommodated within the framework's specific callbacks.

Comment: ajax calls have an attribute async : true/false which can change the nature of the call. if you set async to false, the main UI thread blocks

Comment: @Dragan indeed, didn't want to confuse you with that but glad you noticed. Although asynch false is an option it is really a bad practice, in terms of system and ux performance. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 2):

```
var project = this.store.createRecord('project', {
    name: projectName,
});

project.save().then(function(projectResponse) {
    alert(projectResponse.get('id') + projectResponse.get('name'));
});
```

This would work for sure !! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 savePerson: function(hash){
     return this.store.createRecord('agents/person', hash).save();
    },


  var hash = {
                      given_name : firstname,

         };

  this.savePerson(hash).then(function(record){
                var personModelId = record.get('id');
```

I got mine like That